# Problem about exporting mysql query result into csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I want to export mysql query result into csv file but I found there is something 
wrong with the format of csv file.

Input:

```
COMPANY AMOUNT VENDOR_NAME
    C1   70000           A
    C2    6000           A
    C3    2000           A
    C2   39000           B
    C3    4000           B
    C3   40000           C
```

Output:

```
VENDOR_NAME     C1     C2      C3    Total
          A  
             70000   6000    2000    78000
          B  
                 0  39000    4000    43000
          C  
                 0      0   40000    40000
```

In my output, the vendor name and other numbers are not in the same row... I don't know why. Maybe there are some mistakes in my code.

Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    COMPANY VARCHAR(50),
    AMOUNT DECIMAL(10,2),
    VENDOR_NAME VARCHAR(100)
);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/try.csv' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(COMPANY,AMOUNT,VENDOR_NAME);

SELECT 'VENDOR_NAME','C1','C2','C3','Grand Total'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    VENDOR_NAME,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN COMPANY = 'C1' THEN AMOUNT
            ELSE 0
        END) AS C1,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN COMPANY = 'C2' THEN AMOUNT
            ELSE 0
        END) AS C2,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN COMPANY = 'C3' THEN AMOUNT
            ELSE 0
        END) AS C3,
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS Grand_Total

INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM
    test
GROUP BY VENDOR_NAME;
```

Comment: Unless it's just the way you've shown it here, neither the input or the output appears to be in CSV format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not correctly defining the end of line characters. In Windows you may have to use:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

to read the file properly. It's seems like the  `VENDOR_NAME` column has the the `'\r'` characters at the end of the string.

For more information check [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)